# split elements in array using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big array and a part of that is shown below. in each list, the first number is start and the 2nd number is end (so there is a range). what I want to do is:

1:
 filter out those lists (ranges) which are smaller than 300 (e.g. the 18th list in the following array must be removed)

2:
 get a smaller ranges (lists) in this way: (start+100) to (start+200). e.g the first list would be [ 569, 669].

I tried to use different split functions in numpy but non of them gives what I am looking for.

```
array([[ 469, 1300],
       [ 171, 1440],
       [ 187, 1564],
       [ 204, 1740],
       [  40, 1363],
       [  56, 1457],
       [ 132,  606],
       [1175, 2096],
       [ 484, 2839],
       [ 132, 4572],
       [ 166, 1693],
       [  69, 3300],
       [ 142, 1003],
       [2118, 2118],
       [ 715, 1687],
       [ 301, 1006],
       [  48, 2142],
       [  63,  330],
       [ 479, 2411]], dtype=uint32)
```

do you guys know how to do that in python?

thanks

Comment: Filter should be easy... Python has an explicit filter function

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array is called `A`, then:

```
import numpy as np

# Filter out differences not wanted
gt300 = A[(np.diff(A) >= 300).flatten()]

# Set new value of first column
gt300[:,0] += 100

# Set value of second column
gt300[:,1] = gt300[:,0] + 100
```

Or maybe something like:

```
B = A[:,0][(np.diff(A) >= 300).flatten()]
C = np.repeat(B, 2).reshape((len(B), 2)) + [100, 200]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, when I run the last line it gives this error:   "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Comment: @user3925736 which line exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[ 469, 1300],
        # ...
        [  63,  330],
        [ 479, 2411]]

print(
    filter(lambda v: v[1] - v[0] >= 300, data)
)

print(
    [[v[0] + 100, v[0] + 200] for v in data]
)
```

Explanation:

The first command uses the builtin [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) method to filter the remaining elements based on a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression.

The second iterates over the list and generates a new one while doing so.

If the input and output should be numpy arrays try the following. Note: There is no way to filter an numpy array without creating a new one.

```
data = array([
    ( 469, 1300),
    ( 171, 1440),
    # ...
    (  63,  330),
    ( 479, 2411)], dtype=(uint32, uint32))

print(
    array(filter(lambda v: v[1] - v[0] >= 300, data), dtype=(uint32, uint32))
)

print(
    array([[v[0] + 100, v[0] + 200] for v in data], dtype=(uint32, uint32))
)
```

Comment: HI Simon, great. it works perfectly for matrix (list of lists), but my data is array and I have to get array (that is a numpy array). do you know how to manipulate the input array to get a numpy array like input but with the mentioned changes?

Answer (score 0):

A general note before:
You should use [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to represnt such ranges, not lists, They are immutable data types with a meaning to the order of items in them.

As for 1, it is pretty easy to filter in python:

```
filter(lambda single_range: single_range[1] - single_range[0] > 300, ranges)
```

A clearer way (in my opinion) to do this is with a list comprehension:

```
[(start, end) for start, end in ranges if end - start > 300]
```

As for 2, I don't fully understand what you mean, but if you mean creating a new list of ranges, where each range is changes using a single function, you mean a map (or my preferred way, a list comprehension which is equal but more descriptive):

```
[(start + 100, start + 200) for start, end in ranges]
```

Comment: Hi Ehud, this is a numpy array. and I would like to get the same array for further handling.

Answer (score 0):

We can find which rows have the small difference with:

```
In [745]: mask=(x[:,1]-x[:,0])<300
In [746]: mask
Out[746]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

We can use that `mask` to select those rows, or to deselect them

```
In [747]: x[mask,:]
Out[747]: 
array([[2118, 2118],
       [  63,  330]], dtype=uint32)
In [748]: x[~mask,:]
Out[748]: 
array([[ 469, 1300],
       [ 171, 1440],
       [ 187, 1564],
       [ 204, 1740],
       ...
       [ 479, 2411]], dtype=uint32)
```

To make a new set of ranges; get the first column; here I am using `[0]` so the selection remains a column array:

```
In [750]: x[:,[0]]
Out[750]: 
array([[ 469],
       [ 171],
       [ 187],
        ...
       [  48],
       [  63],
       [ 479]], dtype=uint32)
```

Add to that the desired offsets.  This takes advantage of broadcasting.

```
In [751]: x[:,[0]]+[100,200]
Out[751]: 
array([[ 569,  669],
       [ 271,  371],
       [ 287,  387],
       [ 304,  404],
       [ 140,  240],
       [ 156,  256],
      ...
       [ 401,  501],
       [ 148,  248],
       [ 163,  263],
       [ 579,  679]], dtype=int64)
```

There are other ways of constructing such an array

```
np.column_stack([x[:,0]+100,x[:,0]+200])
np.array([x[:,0]+100, x[:,0]+200]).T   # or vstack
```

Other answers have suggested the `Python` list `filter`.  I'm partial to list comprehensions in this kind of use, for example:

```
In [756]: np.array([i for i in x if (i[1]-i[0])<300])
Out[756]: 
array([[2118, 2118],
       [  63,  330]], dtype=uint32)
```

For small lists of lists, the pure Python approach tends to be faster.  But if the object is already a `numpy` array, it is faster to use the `numpy` operations that work on the whole array at once (i.e. do the iteration in compiled code).  Hence my suggestion to use the boolean mask.